# Visual Studio 2012 Pro - C# - Typed DataSet migration issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, xsd, strongly-typed-dataset

I am rewriting a web application in VS 2012 Pro.  The old application was done in VS 2008 and used several Typed DataSets for db interaction.  I have copied the typed dataset files (.xsd, .cs, .xsc, .xss, .Designer.cs, etc) from the old project to the new.  The new web app (solution) is comprised of 5 projects, all targeting .NET Framework 3.5. I am using a different SQL Server instance (my local test db server) than the original, but the db itself was restored from a backup of the production db.  Also, the prod db is SQL Server 2008 Express, my local is SQL Server 2012 Express.

I can, with no issues, use the existing typed datasets to retrieve and save data hitting my test db.  And btw, the old app used these DataConnection files (.cs and .resx), which I also copied into the new web application to enable usage of the typed datasets.  I did need to change the connection strings of course.

The trouble I am having is that I have added new columns to one of the tables in my test db, but I am unable to update the Typed DataSets to make them aware of the new columns.

I am new to Typed DataSets, and after a couple days research I have learned that you would normally create a data connection thru server explorer then drag table(s) from your db onto a Typed DataSet surface.  Also, I have read that you can refresh or configure the Typed DataSet to make it aware of new columns.  I am unable to do that with these existing (copied in) datasets; when I double-click on an .xsd, and right-click, the menu that pops up has "configure" disabled.

I have even created a new solution, setup all of my projects, and recreated from scratch the data connection and Typed DataSets, but lots of other things break.

In my last working solution, I added a data connection in server explorer to my local test SQL Server db, but it did not help, which may be due to the fact that it is not the same db server as what was used when the original Typed DataSets were created?  To validate this idea I looked thru all of the files for one of the Typed DataSets but found nothing that points to a data connection, so I am unsure if that is in fact an issue.

So, my question is, how can I update an existing Typed DataSet that I copied into a new project?  It is interesting that I can used them as is, but cannot update them.  My guess is that there is a disconnect between the Typed DataSets and the db itself?

Thx

Comment: the files are not read only are they?

Comment: No, they are not.  Good question tho.

Comment: I did find resolution last night and today. And that was to manually add the columns into the DataTables themselves on the Typed DataSet surface! Simply right click, add column, give it the same name as the newly added column in the db table, and in properties set the datatype and default value. I also needed to make updates to the DataConnection.cs class adding SqlParameters for the new columns. Also, the sql statements for the select, insert, update, delete operations are kept in a DataConnection.resx file, and I needed to add the new columns in update and select statements.